# Weblogic custom identity custom trust - unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Tags: java, paypal, certificate, weblogic

I used the following steps to generate my truststore. I found it in a youtube tutorial. After i created everything you can see below, I configured my weblogic server as custom identity and custom trust with my server.jks and servertruststore.jks.

```
keytool -genkeypair -keystore castore.jks -storepass welcome1 -alias rootca -keypass welcome1 -keyalg RSA

keytool -certreq -keystore castore.jks -storepass welcome1 -alias rootca -keypass welcome1 -file rootca.csr -v

keytool -gencert -alias rootca -keypass welcome1 -keystore castore.jks -storepass welcome1 -ext BC=2 -rfc -infile rootca.csr -outfile rootca.cer -v

keytool -importcert -alias rootca -keypass welcome1 -keystore catruststore.jks -storepass welcome1 -file rootca.cer

keytool -genkeypair -keystore server.jks -storepass welcome1 -alias 100bytesServer -keypass welcome1 -keyalg RSA

keytool -certreq -keystore server.jks -storepass welcome1 -alias 100bytesServer -keypass welcome1 -file 100bytesServer.csr -v

keytool -gencert -alias rootca -keypass welcome1 -keystore ..\castore\castore.jks -storepass welcome1 -ext BC=2 -rfc -infile 100bytesServer.csr -outfile 100bytesServer.cer

keytool -importcert -alias rootca -keypass welcome1 -keystore server.jks -storepass welcome1 -file ..\castore\rootca.cer

keytool -importcert -alias 100bytesServer -keypass welcome1 -keystore server.jks -storepass welcome1 -file 100bytesServer.cer

keytool -importcert -alias rootca -keypass welcome1 -keystore servertruststore.jks -storepass welcome1 -file ..\castore\rootca.cer
```

The problem is that i get the following error when trying to make a paypal payment (which works with demoTruststore from weblogic)

> Caused By: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path
>   building failed:
>   sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to
>   find valid certification path to requested target

I know i have to manually import the paypal certificate in my own servertruststore.jks. I have done it, but the error persists. I imported both sandbox.paypal.com and paypal.com certificates.

Please help me with my particular problem. I found a lot of topics, I am a newbie and I could not succeed in resolving that problem. I am kindly asking for  the exact command i have to execute.

Comment: Have you already defined **the javax.net.ssl.trustStore** property in your Weblogic's start parameters?

Comment: No, i didn't know i have to. I am using this to authentify the clients using their certificates (which i generate of course).                                                       So how do i define that property ? i don't know what exactly are you saying. This is my first web app using weblogic and spring mvc.

Comment: I don't think this is the problem, the server loads my truststore. That is actually the problem. If i use their demoTrustStore, everything is working. Now i can't make https requests to other web sites.

Answer (score 0):

When you import a root CA cert into your trust store, you need to provide "–trustcacerts" option to keytool.

Comment: So you're saying that i should import paypal's cert and provide that option in the keytool command ?

Comment: Yes. What is also important is "where" or "which trust store" you import this cert into. I am assuming you know which these trust stores are.

Comment: I did import it in the custom truststore that is used by weblogic server but still not working.